# Getting odbc drivers to work with windows subsystem for linux

Tags: ubuntu, teradata, unixodbc

I am trying to configure the Teradata 16.20.00.54 ODBC drivers to work on Ubuntu (under the windows subsystem for linux). I've been encountering a lot of esoteric errors, so I'm wondering whether it's possible to get this working with the WSL.

(1) I downloaded the teradata driver for ubuntu [here](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/odbc-driver/linux)

(2)Then I followed the instructions to configure the ODBC drivers [here](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/EZAbQ2BX~vKBrWDQ3v7fPQ/jMjjI2tiTSm4ExNu_uG2sg)

This is my setup:

```
$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/myusername/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

$ odbcinst -q -d
odbcinst: SQLGetPrivateProfileString failed with .

$ odbcinst -q -s
[<DSN_name>]

$ cat ~/.odbc.ini
[ODBC Data Sources]

Teradata ODBC DSN = Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20
<DSN_name> = DEVDB

[<DSN_name>]
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdataodbc_sb64.so
Description=Teradatadatabase
DBCName=DEVDB.mycompany.com
UID=XXXXXXX
PWD=XXXXXXX

$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini

$ echo $ODBCINI
/home/myusername/.odbc.ini
```

I'm very inexperienced with teradata so there is likely some issue with my configuration somewhere.

This is the error message that I get:

```
$ isql DEVDB -v
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Comment: 1) remove `Teradata ODBC DSN = Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20` from your .odbc.ini 2)Change `<DSN_Name> = DEVDB` to `<DSN_NAME>=tdataodbc_sb64.so`. Also, I'm assuming that your `<DSN_NAME>` in this question is actually a DSN name in your real `.odbc.ini`... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you interpreted the configuration example a bit too literally. For a DSN named DEVDB your .odbc.ini would look more like this:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
DEVDB=Teradata Database ODBC Driver

[DEVDB]
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/tdataodbc_sb64.so
Description=Teradatadatabase
DBCName=DEVDB.mycompany.com
UID=XXXXXXX
PWD=XXXXXXX
```